# Cant find out how can I compare two manytomany fields and show the result in context

Tags: python, django, django-models

So, I am doing a project where there are posts of 3 categories (movies(model name="List"), music(model name="MusicList"), books(model name="BookList")) each category is a model. and each model has its own genre set model (Genre, MusicGenre, BookGenre).

There is a profile model which has - favourite_music_genre, favourite_movie_genre & favourite_book_genre.

So now in my all(homepage) function in views I want to have some codes that will compare current logged in users favourite_music_genre, favourite_movie_genre & favourite_book_genre and show only the List, MusicList & BookList of the matched genres.

For example if a users selected fav_genre is Action & Comedy. It will only show the lists which has Action & Comedy genre.

Im new to python/django. Been scratching my head for past 4/6 days. couldn't figure out the way.

In my Models.py

```
class MusicList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('MusicGenre')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Music")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}|{self.creator}'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title + str(self.posted))
        super(MusicList,self).save(*args, **kwargs)



class MusicGenre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class BookList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('BookGenre')
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    spoiler_choices = [(False, 'No'),(True, 'Yes')]
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, choices = spoiler_choices)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="book")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}|{self.creator}'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title + str(self.posted))
        super(BookList,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class BookGenre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('Genre')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = RichTextField(null=True,default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Movie")
    spoiler_choices = [(False, 'No'),(True, 'Yes')]
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, choices = spoiler_choices)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}|{self.creator}'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title + str(self.posted))
        super(List,self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='', upload_to='profiles_pics')
    fav_music_genre = models.ManyToManyField('MusicGenre')
    fav_Book_genre = models.ManyToManyField('BookGenre')
    fav_movie_genre = models.ManyToManyField('Genre')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " | bio : " + self.bio

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the books, you could try something like

```
BookList.objects.filter(genre__id__in=current_profile.fav_Book_genre.values_list("id", flat=True))
```

If it works you'll be able to do the same for movies and musics

Comment: did this. Its throwing in this error - 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'values_list'

Comment: Oh, try fav_Book_genre.all().values_list... I hope it is clear that the "profile" in my answer is the current profile you're trying to display books for.

Comment: yes its connected to the user so isn't it suppose to refer to the current logged in user? and by addding all() its showing this error 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: It is weird, the error you get is often met when you're using the model instead of an instance. Like Profile.fav_Book_genre.all()

Comment: actually in here Profile is a model and fav_Book_genre is a field of that model which is a manytomanyfield referring to BookGenre model.

Comment: I do agree, but to get fav_Book_genre for a specific profil, you need the instance of the said profile. Like current_user.profile . Anyway could you share the piece of code ?

Comment: I see I thought it takes the current logged in users profile by default. any idea how can I pass the current users profile???

Comment: I would need to know where this piece of code get executed in your app. If this get triggered by a request you could get request.user

Comment: yeah tried this - ` madefb = List.objects.filter(genre_id__in= request.user.Profile.fav_movie_genre.all().values_list("id", flat=True))`   . And now its throwing in this error - 'User' object has no attribute 'Profile'

Comment: Try profile not Profile

Comment: Oh I put Profile coz that was my models name. But now changed to profile. Its showing error `Cannot resolve keyword 'genre_id' into field. Choices are: content, creator, creator_id, genre, id, posted, review, slug, spoiler, title, type`. Then I changed it to id and its blank. actually clouded up here dont know what im doin. sorry

Comment: That's my bad, it should be genre__id

Comment: It worked. U are a life saver man!